# Angular - How to insert multiple FormGroups to a FormArray?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to insert FormGroups into a FormArray before a component is loaded. This is my FormGroup:

```
/*constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {}*/
this.productGroup = this.fb.group({
 name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80)])],
  variants: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      _id: '',
      type: '',
      options: ''
    })
  ]),
});
```

And this is how I'm inserting a FormGroup inside `variants` FormArray:

```
const variants = <FormArray>this.productGroup.controls.variants;
variants.push(this.fb.group({ _id: '', type: '', options: '' }));
```

Problem is, `variants.length` value can be 3, 4 and so on. How to deal with it?

```
// variants.lenght == 2
variants.push(this.fb.group({ _id: '', type: '', options: '' }));
variants.push(this.fb.group({ _id: '', type: '', options: '' }));

// variants.lenght == 3
variants.push(this.fb.group({ _id: '', type: '', options: '' }));
variants.push(this.fb.group({ _id: '', type: '', options: '' }));
variants.push(this.fb.group({ _id: '', type: '', options: '' }));
```

Comment: I answered your question, but I am actually thinking, what do you want to achieve? Perhaps I have missed what you are looking for?

Comment: @jburtondev Im pushing the whole object from database, so `variants` length is variable

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you mean, it will cause an infinite n+1 loop. So the  variants length should stay the same right? You just want to add as many new groups as there are arrays into your Form Array?

Comment: Yes, I need to have the same amount of form groups as variants, so it will be ready for patching the values from database.

Comment: Cool, perfect just writing the answer.

Comment: @jburtondev thanks. I've realized my mistake now... there is already one formgroup declared when the function is called

Comment: No problem, glad to hear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FormArray` method only accepts one control as an argument, therefore you can only add one `FormGroup` at a time: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.0.2/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1582-L1593

You can use a for loop to iterate over all of the controls and push them in one by one, if you have multiple `FormGroup` items that you would like to add.

Use this:

```
const dataBaseVariantsLength = objectFromDataBaseLength;
for (let i = 0; i < dataBaseVariantsLength; i++) {
  variants.push(this.fb.group({ _id: '', type: '', options: '' }));
}
```